# Bounded linear operator and self adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis

these questions are in my workbook but there is no worked solutions whatsoever. I dont know where to begin with this at all. Any help would be much appreciated. Thankyou

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M_c(x) = (c_1 x_1, c_2 x_2,...)$. It is easy to see that
$\| M_c (x) \|^2 = \sum_k |c_k|^2 |x_k|^2  \le \sum_k |x_k|^2 = \|x\|_2$,
and so $\|M_c\| \le 1$. Noting that $\|M_c (e_n)\| = |c_n|$, shows that $\|M_c \| = 1$.

If $y = M_c x$, then we have $y_k = c_k x_k$, so if it is invertible, we must have
$x_k = {1 \over c_k} y_k$, that is, the inverse will be the multiplication operator with value $\kappa = ({1 \over c_1}, {1 \over c_2},...)$. To be invertible, we need $c_k \neq 0$ for all $k$, otherwise $M_c e_n = 0$ for some $n$, which would mean that $M_c$ is not invertible.
Since $|c_k|$ is increasing and bounded above, this implies $c_1 \neq 0 $.

It is easy to see that if $c_1 \neq 0$, then ${1 \over |c_k|} \le {1 \over |c_1|}$ for all $k$, hence the operator $A(x) = ({1 \over c_1}x_1, {1 \over c_2} x_2,...)$ is continuous and satisfies $A( M_c(x)) = x$ for all $x$, hence $M_c$ is invertible.

To be self-adjoint, we need $M_c = M_c^*$.

This is true **iff** $\langle e_i, M_c e_j \rangle = \langle M_c e_i,  e_j \rangle $
for all $i,j$ **iff** ${ 1 \over c_j } \delta_{ij} = { 1 \over \bar{c_i} } \delta_{ij} $ for all $i,j$ **iff** $\bar{c_i} = c_i$ for all $i$ **iff** $c_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $i$.

Comment: Thankyou, you explained this a lot clearer than earlier explanations in my work book and this answer helped me a lot. Cheers :)

Comment: The Mathematical Shillelagh strikes down another one!

Comment: @1950RobertLewis: With the help of a little two-buck-chuck! Functional analysis and cabernet sauvignon go well together. All I need now is some of the Med's quesadillas...

Comment: @copper.hat:  Myself, I like *cannabis* with *complex analysis* and PDEs!  Check out my new enhanced profile!  Hmmm, speaking of quesadilla's, I wonder if the kitchen is still serving them at this hour . . .

Comment: @1950RobertLewis: Yes, PDEs definitely need something stronger than 2BC...

Comment: @copper.hat:  I find *Blue Dream* good for nonlinear elliptic oerators as well as Atiyah-Singer index theory!

Comment: @1950RobertLewis: I gather amphetamines were Erdős' choice of inspiration...

Comment: @copper.hat:  I'm with Willie Nelson on that one:  he told his band members, "You're wired, you're fired!"

Comment: @1950RobertLewis: Erdős won a $500 bet by stopping for a month...

Comment: @copper.hat:  I wonder where *that* money went?

Comment: @1950RobertLewis: Into more theorems...

Comment: @copper.hat:  math, meth, what's the difference? ;-)! man, that 2BC has got you goin' tonight!  Tried to order a a quesadilla in your honor but the kitchen was closing.

Comment: @1950RobertLewis: Definitely a math addict...

Comment: @copper.hat:  who, me?  I admitted I was powerless over mathematics, that my life had become unmanageable . . . maybe should have meetings! ;-)!  But we'd probably end up just doing more math!

Comment: @1950RobertLewis: I meant myself :-)

Comment: @copper.hat:  birds of a feather . . .

Comment: @1950RobertLewis: Have a good night, I need to hit the sack!

Comment: @copper.hat:  beunas noches, amigo!

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem, note that
$$
\|M_c\| = \sup_{\|x\|_2=1} \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty |c_n x_n| \right)^{1/2}
$$
It is fairly easy to show that $1$ gives us an upper bound for this infinite sum.  Why is it also the least-upper bound?

For the second: note that if $M_c$ is invertible, its inverse would have to be $M_d$ with $d = \{\frac 1{c_n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$

For the third: as a means of intuition, when is a diagonal matrix self-adjoint?

Comment: Thankyou for this. I used this hint and had a look back before confirming my answer with the second answer on here. Thanks again !